# How can a trait compiled from an AST at runtime be accessed from further reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using scala 2.10's toolbox api to compile and construct classes from ASTs at runtime. I have an AST for a trait which I want to compile and mix in to future class definitions but am unable to get any handle with which to apply it to my class.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@7469d79a

scala> val ast_trait = tb.parse("trait T")//My AST is manually constructed starting with ClassDef
ast_trait: tb.u.Tree = abstract trait T extends scala.AnyRef

//compile and execute the tree
scala> tb.eval(ast_trait)
res0: Any = ()

//attempt to define a class that 
scala> tb.eval(tb.parse("class C extends T"))implements T. In my code this is a constructed AST
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

not found: type T
/*stack trace*/
```

This fails as when classes/traits are compiled with a toolbox, they are wrapped and given a name like __wrapper$[wrapCount]$[uuid]$[name].

The problem arises of how to obtain a handle to the defined trait to be used with the class definition.

The apparent solution was to obtain a `scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Type` instance for the trait via `typeOf[T]`.

```
//Obtain an AST via tb.parse
scala> val ast_type = tb.parse("scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[T]")
ast_type: tb.u.Tree = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[T]

//eval the trait defintion and typeOf in the same block
scala> tb.eval(Block(ast_trait, ast_type))
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

No TypeTag available for T
not enough arguments for method typeOf: (implicit ttag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.Type.
Unspecified value parameter ttag.
/*stack trace*/
```

I'm not entirely sure why this fails, but I have not succeded in working with implicit type tags and toolbox compilation in any form before.

```
//A simpler all in one example
scala> tb.eval(tb.parse("trait T; scala.reflect.runtime.universe.typeOf[T]"))
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

No TypeTag available for T
not enough arguments for method typeOf: (implicit ttag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.Type.
Unspecified value parameter ttag.
/*stack trace*/
```

Is there a way to disable the wrapping so that the trait will be defined with the name specified in the AST?

If not, how can the fullName of the trait be acquired?

**Update:** The suggestion of using `classOf` worked like a charm, until the trait was actually applied to a class.

```
scala> val mirror = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

scala> val clazz = tb.eval(tb.parse("trait T{def m = 0}; classOf[T]")).asInstanceOf[Class[_]]
clazz: Class[_] = interface __wrapper$5$36e5027b48a44570a47be32d536aa67d.__wrapper$5$36e5027b48a44570a47be32d536aa67d$T$1
scala> val tpe = mirror.classSymbol(clazz)
tpe: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = trait T$1

scala> val tree = ClassDef(Modifiers(), "C", List(), Template(
     | List(Ident(tpe)),
     | emptyValDef,
     | List()))
tree: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassDef = class C extends T$1

scala> tb.eval(tree)
scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:

class C needs to be abstract, since method m in trait T$1 of type ()Int is not defined
/*stack trace*/
```

It appears that the implementation of the trait is being lost and it is being applied as just an interface (which is what the java class returned by classOf defines).

I hypothesise that toolbox's wrapper is renaming the java class for the implementation of the trait (normally with the same classname followed by '$') with a new uuid and the compiler is then unable to find it and assumes it is just an interface.

How can I apply the trait with implementation to a class?

Comment: The typeOf thing looks like a bug. Could you please submit it to our JIRA? Have you tried classOf though?

Comment: Your second problem happens because the compiler wraps all code sent to eval into a wrapper. E.g. `2` gets transformed into `object blahblah { def blah = 2 }`. Therefore your trait ends up becoming a local trait, and for local types Scala doesn't preserve any metadata for reflection. Thus later on Scala treats T as a plain Java interface, not knowing that it has actually an implementation. This can be fixed by omitting the wrapping in some cases.

Comment: So now I have 2 questions: 1) Could you please submit a bug to JIRA, so that we have a point of reference? 2) Is this a blocker for you?